# Font size doesn't change when using clamp()

Tags: css

I just discovered clamp and would like to use it to set up the font size. I would like the min value to be .8rem, for mobile version. Then 1 rem for ideal size, and then 1.25rem when the screen gets bigger. But the font-size doesn't change at all when I re-size the screen.

I tried clamp(10px, 15px, 20px), it didn't work, either.

```js
    *{
      margin: 0;
    }
    body{
      background-color: rgb(118, 120, 245);
      height: 100vh;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
    }
    .container{
      background-color: white;
      width: 60%;
      max-width: 500px;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
    }
    p{
      font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
      font-size: clamp(1rem, .8rem, 1.5rem);
    }
```

```html
  <div class="container">
    <p>A Message You Would Like To Pass</p>
    <input type="text">
    <button>Submit</button>
    <p>Last Message Delivered!</p>
    <p>Hello World</p>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its better
clamp(mobile, standart, desktop)
Enter value for mobile and desktop. then change the middle value according to the situation.

```
  font-size:clamp(15px, 1.5vw, 20px);
```

Comment: This works. However, if I put in clamp(10px, 16px, 20px), it always stays 16px. Is there an explanation ?

Comment: you can change center unit. "1.5vw" increase or decrease.
my method is: desktop mode I change the middle vw value and get the maximum value. I enter that value in the middle.

vw=viewport width =references the page width.
clamp is new property for CSS you can google it. I guess I can't explain it fully.

Answer (score 0):

The function takes three parameters: a minimum value, a preferred value, and a maximum allowed value.

so if your first value (1rem) is higher then the middle one (.8rem) it will not work.

i think what you want is:

```
font-size: clamp(12px, (Set value here)vw, 20px);
```

btw use px for the first and last value.

Comment: This works. However, if I put in clamp(10px, 16px, 20px), it always stays 16px. Is there an explanation ?

Comment: like i said the middle number is what it wants to be. Use vw, %, rem usw for the middle number. If you write 16px it will always be 16px because 16 pixel are never dmaller then 10px for example.